# Django 1.4: DeprecationWarning with django.template.loader.render_to_string

Tags: python, django, warnings, deprecated

```
Django version 1.4.3

class FooTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_deprecation_warning(self):

        from django.template.loader import render_to_string
        tpl = render_to_string('template.html')
```

at runtime this generates a `DeprecationWarning`

```
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\simple.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Function-based generic views have been deprecated; use class-based views instead.
```

why? it's not mentioned in the migration page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views-migration/

Comment: Are you sure that it's `render_to_string` that's giving you the warning? Can you show us the backtrace?

Comment: how can i generate the backtrace for a deprecation warning?

Comment: Set `warnings.filterwarnings('error')` and then you get an exception instead of a warning ([see the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)).

Comment: I guess that's cause your class doesn't inherit from `TemplateView`, hence Django considers your approach to be function-based.

Comment: And here's some more explanation. Class-based views were introduced in 1.3 actually. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#templateview

Comment: no it's not that the problem. render_to_string is, if i don't use it deprecation error goes away. i'm trying to debug the warning (as suggested by Gareth) but i get also a bunch of PendingDeprecationWarning

Answer (score 1):

You can get a traceback for this warning by a Python *warning control* command line option `-W` to see easy what uses the deprecated `django.views.generic.simple`.

```
python -W error:::django.views.generic.simple manage.py test
```

Your test case does not report any DeprecationWarning for a simple template.html with Django 1.4. You probably use an obsoleted template tag that imports this deprecated module.

More info for
[Python warning control](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W)
and DeprecationWarning are in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16457346/448474).