# Verbose deprecation warnings in Django

Tags: python, django, warnings, django-1.5, deprecation-warning

After upgrading from django 1.3 to django 1.5 I started to see these `DeprecationWarnings` during the test run:

> path_to_virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/http/request.py:193:
>   DeprecationWarning: HttpRequest.raw_post_data has been deprecated. Use
>   HttpRequest.body instead.

I've searched inside the project for `raw_post_data` and found nothing. So it was not directly used in the project. Then, I've manually went through `INSTALLED_APPS` and found that `raven` module still uses `raw_post_data` and it was the cause, but..

Is it possible to see the cause of `DeprecationWarning` during the test run? How to make these warnings more verbose?

Comment: Can you show how you make the request? There must be something accessing the `raw_post_data` property even though it shouldn't.

Comment: It's simply `self.client.get(url, params)`. I'm pretty sure it's not relevant, because I do make such requests in many test methods, but only this one causes the warning to appear. So I guess this is because something is imported in `libs` that causes the warning. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: I see. Are you importing anything in `libs` that is related to Django or requests / views ? In Django 1.5 the `raw_post_data` property is not accessed but something could be analysing the request by iterating over all properties. Perhaps `mock`? Or something in `libs`?

Comment: There is a bunch of imports in `libs`, but nothing related to requests/views, except that there is `from django.conf import settings`. And..here it is: raven is the cause - figured it out manually. Thank you, but I still want to know if I could have seen the cause during the test run somehow. I'll update the question.

Comment: I don't think you can. The `raw_post_data` property is accessed but when the `DeprecationWarning` is raised you won't know who accessed it. So there's no flag that can be enabled to make it more verbose.

Comment: Yes, but, as I understand, first I should somehow (may be with the help of `warnings` module) make django treat warnings as errors, then I should get the traceback during this warning and throw it to the stdout. Thank you for help anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is taken from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266765/django-track-down-causes-of-deprecationwarning).

You can use the warnings modules to raise an error for `DeprecationWarning`.

Temporarily add the following snippet to the top of your project's `urls.py`:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('error', DeprecationWarning)
```

The `DeprecationWarning` will now raise an error, so if `debug=True` you'll get the familiar yellow Django error page with the full traceback.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work - when I add this to `urls.py` or `settings.py` I don't see warnings during the test run at all. I'll try to figure out why and accept the answer if it works. Thank you for participation.

Comment: Found it, the problem was in `raven` itself. It was eating all type of exceptions while accessing `raw_post_data` - that's why I saw warnings and I didn't see exceptions at the same place (see [source](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/master/raven/contrib/django/client.py#L71)). So, provided solution works. Thank you!

Comment: @SunnySydeUp, decided to accept your answer, but to give a bounty award to hynekcer for his awesome alternative solution. Hope it seems fair to you too.

Answer (score 24):

You can set [Python warning control](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) by command line option `-W` to raise an exception with a **traceback** on **DeprecationWarning** like for errors instead of normal simple warning once. Any specific warning can by filtered by message, category, module, line or by a combination of them.

Examples:

```
python -W error:"raw_post_data has been deprecated" manage.py test

python -W error::DeprecationWarning manage.py test

python -W error:::django.http.request manage.py test
```

A fine filtering is useful if you want to fix all warnings of one type together by batch editing in many files of a big project.

---

*Python 2.7* and higher ignores DeprecationWarning usually if they are not reanabled, e.g. by `-Wd` option or by the environment variable `export PYTHONWARNINGS="d"`. That can be useful on development machines but not on production.