# Is there a way to detect statically deprecated modules in a Python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, deprecation-warning

I am struggling checking statically if my Python 3 project relies on deprecated libraries. As it contains many third party modules downloaded via pip, it becomes cumbersome to check them one by one.

I know that warnings appear when you execute code that contains deprecated functions, but I would like to do that statically by scanning the requirements.txt of my project. I also know that Pylint has a checker that detects imports of modules that are marked as deprecated in the pylintrc, but you need to know in advance which modules you want to mark as deprecated.

So how can I scan my project in order to check if some of the libraries I use are deprecated, and this without executing the project?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27336824/14316282) helps? Voted your question up so hopefully somebody with more knowledge can help out anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already seen this answer but I don’t feel comfortable enough with ASTs to work with it. But I will consider this solution if no other is given.